# Transfer non-App Store iOS Apps to another iOS Enterprise Developer Account

Tags: ios

My company is using an iOS Personal Developer Account as we were having trouble to get an DUNS number. We have developed several apps and distributed internally, by using an AdHoc mobileprovision file and add UDID for every device.

Now we have reached the 100 devices limit of the Personal Account, we are applying for the Enterprise one.

The problem here is I want to transfer existing app to the new Enterprise account, without changing the bundle id, so the saved files on users' devices can be kept during updating. If I use a new bundle id, the user will see two apps with the same name and icon and function on their device.

I understand Apple has announced the way to transfer apps on App Store, but our apps are not on App Store.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been able to transfer an app from an Enterprise Account to an App Store account. Maybe the same process works for Enterprise to Enterprise: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43974991/588314

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do it without changing the bundle id, as it's unique across all developers accounts.

Also, the new iTunes Connect won't help.

Comment: Would remove the app id from first account and re-add it into the second work? I don't have the courage to try as I think it could pause the apps from running on users' devices

Comment: No, because you won't be able to recreate an app with the same identifier. You can test it by creating a dummy app on your App Store account, delete it and trying to create it again on the Enterprise account.

Comment: I think I'm going to use new bundle ids for the apps